# Sampling nested lists in reverse using comprehension

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

Sorry if this is a duplicate. If I have a list of lists:

```
j0 = [i for i in range(4)]
j1 = [j0 for j in range(4)]
>>> [[0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2, 3]]
```

I can get an element from each list in turn using a list comprehension:

```
print [j1[k][k] for k in range(0,4)]
>>> [0, 1, 2, 3]
```

But I want an element from each list starting from the end (so working backwards), so the desired output is:

```
>>> [3, 2, 1, 0]  # One item from each list
```

I tried this but its obviously wrong because j1[0][0] = 0:

```
print [j1[k][-k] for k in range(0,4)]
>>>[0, 3, 2, 1]
```

I can use the following, but is there a nicer way using a list comprehension?

```
nl = []
l = 0
for i in range(-1, -5, -1):
    nl.append(j1[l][i])
    l += 1
print nl
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is very similar to what you have tried.  You had the right idea with `-k`, but have to subtract it from the length (along with another `-1` since python indices start at `0`).

```
print [j1[k][len(j0) - 1 - k] for k in range(0,4)]
[3, 2, 1, 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try

```
print [j1[k][k] for k in range(3, -1, -1)]
```